# Friedman Test in R

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a Friedman's test in `R` on some non-normally distributed data on crab and lobster weight landed in Wales each month which looks like this:

```
Year Month Species Value
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1  2008 Jan   Crab    10.6 
2  2008 Jan   Lobster  2.00
3  2008 Feb   Crab    18.1 
4  2008 Feb   Lobster  6.23
5  2008 Mar   Crab    13.3 
6  2008 Mar   Lobster  4.78
```

It carries on like this for every month between 2008 and 2019. When I try and perform a Friedman's test to test for differences between species and year using this code:

```
pot_fried = friedman.test(Value ~ Species * Year, data = weight)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in friedman.test.formula(Value ~ Species * Year, data = weight) :
> incorrect specification for 'formula'

I then tried using this code:

```
pot_fried = friedman.test(Value ~ Species | Year, data = weight)
```

and got the following error message:

> Error in friedman.test.default(c(10.576198, 1.997196, 18.127488, 6.230985,  :
> not an unreplicated complete block design

I am still quite new to `R` and still getting to grips with the terminology and coding terms used in it. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this code so it works?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the second example on the manual page for the function (`?friedman.test`). You first need to compute the means for each category and then use those in the test. Something like this (untested without reproducible data):

```
weight.means <- aggregate(Value~Species+Year, weight, mean)
friedman.test(Value~Species | Year, weight.means)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I didn't know about having to aggregate the data and calculate the means first, I had a feeling I needed to do something with the data first before running the analysis first.

The test has produced a significant P value,  so that is telling me there is a significant difference in crab and lobster abundances between years correct?

Comment: Yes. If the sample of data you provided is representative, crab is 2 - 3 times more than lobster.

Comment: I'm now trying to perform a post-hoc Nemenyi's test to test for pairwise differences. I have installed the package PMCMRplus as the old PMCMR is now defunct. I enter the code:
frdAllPairsNemenyiTest(f)

f being the Friedman's test I conducted earlier. I get the following output:
"Error in frdRanks(y, groups, blocks) : 
  argument "groups" is missing, with no default"

Comment: Read the manual page for `frdAllPairsNemenyiTest()`. It does not accept whatever object `f` is. It requires the data and the specification of the grouping variable.